# Xml Signature in Java but only on elements where attribute authenticate='true'

Tags: java, xml, xml-signature

I have been able to sign and verify my XML signature when using Apache Santuario, but now I want to only apply the signature to fields where the attribute `authenticate="true"`

For example:

```xml
<Document>
  <DoNotSign></DoNotSign>
  <DoSign authenticate="true"></DoSign>
  <Something>
    <SomethingElse authenticate="true"></SomethingElse>
  </Someting>
</Document>
```

Can anyone help me understand how to achieve it?

I add the reference URI like so:

```java
xmlSignature.addDocument("#xpointer(//*[@authenticate='true'])", transforms, Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);
```

And just get an exception:

```
Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: 
Could not find a resolver for URI #xpointer(//*[@authenticate='true'])
```

I have tried adding the following:

```java
transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_XPOINTER);
xmlSignature.getSignedInfo().addResourceResolver(new ResolverXPointer());
```

This returns me an exception when adding the `XPOINTER` transform.
The `ResolverXPointer` seems to have no effect.

```
TransformationException: Unknown transformation. 
No handler installed for URI http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-xptr-20010108
```

The complete method is below:

```java
final var transforms = new Transforms(document);
transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_ENVELOPED_SIGNATURE);
transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_XPOINTER);

xmlSignature.addDocument("#xpointer(//*[@authenticate='true'])", transforms, Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);
xmlSignature.addKeyInfo(signingCertificate);
xmlSignature.sign(signingKey);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue I created a custom ResourceResolverSPI and added it

```
  ResourceResolver.register(new XPathResourceResolver(), true);
```

That solved the issue, the custom resolver just uses XPath to create a Set for signing.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your XPathResourceResolver class?